# how should I fix input size in keras model

Tags: keras, model, mnist, softmax, mlp

I want to implement MNIST with MLP using keras, for beginning I just use 2 layer, but I got the error:"expected activation_9 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 10)".How can I fix it?
**

```
input_shape = x_train[0].shape
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
mdl=model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=128)
```

**

Comment: Just use Flatten()

Answer (score 0):

As your first layer try using:

```
tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
```

The dense layer needs a 1-dimensional array but the images are 2d. This layer flattens them to 1d

Answer (score 0):

Dense expects usually 2-d data (batch, _). So, you need to use Flatten() or better use Conv2D layers with Flatten() which is better suited for image classification tasks.